# Как заполнить таблицу с помощью словаря? (Django)

Tags: python, django

Есть словарь, который возвращается в шаблон и имеет следующий вид:

```
dict = {"projects": Project.objects.all(), "errors": Error.objects.all(), "programmers": Developer.objects.all()}
```

Можно ли как-то вывести элемент каждого ключевого слова по очереди и при этом не использовать цикл для отдельного ключевого слова? На подобии:

```
{% for item in projects %}
  {{ print(projects.name) }}
{% endfor %}

{% for item in errors %}
  {{ print(errors.name) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Т.е. нужно, чтобы сначала вывелся первый элемент "projects", потом второй элемент "errors", потом третий элемент "programmers" и по новой.

Таким образом нужно заполнить таблицу:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>{{ "Первый элемент projects" }}</td>
     <td>{{ "Первый элемент errors" }}</td>
     ...
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>{{ "Второй элемент projects" }}</td>
     <td>{{ "Второй элемент errors" }}</td>
     ...
   </tr>
   ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно стоит изменить возвращаемый словарь из в вью.

```
lst = zip(projects, errors, programmers)
return render_to_response('template.html', {'lst': lst, ... })
```

И в шаблоне использовать

```
{% for projects, errors, programmers in lst %}
```